# Sync Class state in Svelte

Tags: svelte

I have a class with some methods that update its state. The true state of the class goes out of sync in Svelte, which I know is the correct behaviour, because there are no new assignments. What would be the best approach to ensuring the state of the object remains syncronised with the DOM?

Here is an example REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/394676df2221456d923f23acc03c3f76?version=3.46.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`writable`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store-writable) stores:

> Function that creates a store which has values that can be set from
> 'outside' components.

Working example: https://svelte.dev/repl/e7bb5633696d4e939c90f701bce2cfb2?version=3.46.4

---

You can maybe create a custom store, like in the [Custom stores](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/custom-stores) tutorial, for example:

```
export function makeUser(name, age){
    const {update, subscribe} = writable({
        loading: false,
        name,
        age
    })
    
    return {
        incrementAge: async () => {
          update((s) => ({...s, loading: true}))
            
          await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000))
        
          update((s) => ({...s, age: s.age + 1, loading: false }))
        },
        subscribe,
    }
}
```

Working example: https://svelte.dev/repl/4ff2b92282b8455387357529ccb9e3a9?version=3.46.4

Comment: Would this be considered best practice? I feel like there should be another approach.

Comment: You can create a custom store, see my update.